# Display Profile Photo of Partner Users in a VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, html, custom-controller

I have a requirement to display FullphotoURL of Partner Users in a VF page which are of 700 (Pagination can be applied to display in multiple pages).

It should be displayed with the name of the User beneath the photo (as medium icons in our folder)

Is there any way to display so. Can anyone help me out here

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you have started creating the VF page then post the code and any specific errors that are occurring when you try to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SLDS Class and repeat attribute to achieve this. Did you try this. Check the below sample code.

VF:

```
<apex:page controller="newStackOverFlowController">
<apex:repeat value="{!users}" var="user">
<table>
<tr>
<span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar_circle slds-avatar_large">
<img alt="{!user.Name}" src="{!user.SmallPhotoUrl}" title="{!user.Name}" /><br/>
{!user.Name}
</span>
</tr>
</table>
 </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public inherited sharing class newStackOverFlowController {

    public list<user> users {get; set;}

    public newStackOverFlowController() {
        users = [SELECT Id, Name, SmallPhotoUrl FROM User WHERE Isactive = true AND IsProfilePhotoActive = true];
    }
}
```

[image]